# How to make a .vimrc command dependent on a file existing?

Tags: vim, vimrc

My `.vimrc` uses pathogen by doing

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

However if I set up a new computer and haven't installed pathogen with

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle && \
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

Then every time I go to edit a file I get a message about pathogen not working (and then I can edit the file).

I'd like my .vimrc call to `execute pathogen#infect` be dependent on `~/.vim/autoload` actually existing.

In shell scripting I would do something like

```
if test -f ~/.vim/autoload
  execute pathogen#infect()
fi
```

but of course that gives undefined method test.  `.vimrc` uses a different syntax like having `"` instead of `#` for comments and for a conditional I don't know what the right format is.

What format I would use for a `.vimrc` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filereadable()` or `isdirectory()` would be better choices than `findfile()` -- the latter one searches in a set of directories. BTW, `findfile()` returns nothing (an empty string) on my system for `~/.vim`

However, `isdirectory()` cannot process `~/`, but `fnamemodify()` comes to the rescue.

```
if isdirectory(fnamemodify('~/.vim/autoload', ':p'))
    execute pathogen#infect()
endif
```

`isdirectory($HOME.'/.vim/autoload')` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
if findfile("~/.vim/autoload")
  execute pathogen#infect()
endif
```